# Универсальная функция склонения числительных не склоняет, если больше 100

Tags: javascript, jquery

Написал функцию которая принимает на вход число и массив с суффиксами.

И вроде бы было нормально пока не перевалил за 100
пробовал нарезать с помощью slice но результат тот же (склоняться перестало)

выходит не такая уж она и универсальная, подскажите что не так в ней?

```js
a = ['дерево', 'дерева', 'деревьев'];
b = ['день', 'дня', 'дней'];

console.log(skl(19, b));
console.log(skl(148, a));

function skl(num, titles) {
  suffix = titles[(num % 100 > 4 && num % 100 <= 20) ? 2 : (num % 10 < 5 && num % 10 > 1) ? 1 : 0];
  return (suffix);
}
```

Comment: Чисто из праздного любопытства: для чего там jquery?

Comment: @websnap вначале хотел использовать html селекторы, из них выбирать число и в них же вставлять суффиксы, но потом решил сократить, так как эта часть непринципиальна, ну а строчка осталась)

Comment: *вроде бы было нормально пока не перевалил за 100* `console.log(skl(48, a));` :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант

```js
var a = ['дерево', 'дерева', 'деревьев'];
var b = ['день', 'дня', 'дней'];

console.log(pluralize(19, b));
console.log(pluralize(148, a));
console.log(pluralize(1003, b));

function pluralize (num, titles) {
    var plural;
    plural = num % 10 === 1 && num % 100 !== 11 ? 0 : num % 10 >= 2 && num % 10 <= 4 && (num % 100 < 10 || num % 100 >= 20) ? 1 : 2;
    switch (plural) {
        case 0:
            return titles[0];
        case 1:
            return titles[1];
        case 2:
            return titles[2];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Исправил, основываясь на ответе Алексей Матвеев

```js
var a = ['дерево', 'дерева', 'деревьев'];
var b = ['день', 'дня', 'дней'];

console.log(pluralize(19, b));
console.log(pluralize(148, a));
console.log(pluralize(1003, b));

function pluralize(num, titles) {
  suffix = titles[num % 10 === 1 && num % 100 !== 11 ? 0 : num % 10 >= 2 && num % 10 <= 4 && (num % 100 < 10 || num % 100 >= 20) ? 1 : 2];
  return suffix;
};
```